# How can I include some specific css file in the prod grunt file?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-build-control

I am new to grunt and I am struggling with this problem.
So I am working on a project where we use separate grunt configs for dev and prod.

The problem is that when I work on the dev server I have access to all css files.
On prod server all css files are minifed and put into one css file

https://xxx/styles.a1a34405694a04f0edd0.css

The `gruntfile-dist.js` file looks like this

```
'use strict';

// Grunt file for distribution only
// Removed tasks for dev
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Configurable paths for the application
    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'webapp',
        // Web Application Sources should be defined on a /src/main/webapp folder
        sources: '${basedir}/src/main/webapp',
        // Test sources should be defined on /src/test
        testSources: '${basedir}/src/test',
        // Target folder where all generated files are placed
        target: '${project.build.directory}',
        // Documentation folder defined on target/docs folder
        docs: '${project.build.directory}/docs',
        // Distribution folder defined on target/dist folder    
        dist: '${project.build.directory}/dist'
    };
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-appcache', 'grunt-polyfill-builder');
    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Project settings
        yeoman: appConfig,        
        appcache: {
            options: {
                basePath: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            },
            all: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/offline.manifest',
                cache: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*',
                network: '*',
                fallback: ['404.html']
            }
        },
        // Replace url of image in dist/main.css file.
        replace: {
            manifest: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/offline.manifest'],
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/offline.manifest',
                replacements: [
                    {
                        from: 'dist/',
                        to: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            target: {
                files: [{
                        dot: true,
                        src: [
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/*.{ico,png,txt}',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/.htaccess',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/*.html',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/views',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/images',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/styles',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/fonts',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/components',
                            '<%= yeoman.target %>/scripts'
                        ]
                    }]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                    }
                ]
            },
            docs: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: '<%= yeoman.docs %>'
                    }
                ]
            },
            server: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: '<%= yeoman.target %>/.tmp'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.target %>/index.html'],
                ignorePath: /\.\.\//
            },
            sass: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.target %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
            }
        },
        // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.sources %>',
                cssDir: '<%= yeoman.target %>/css',
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.target %>/images',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/components/assets',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.target %>/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.target %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/images',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false,
                assetCacheBuster: false,
                sourcemap: true,
                raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    environment: 'production'
                }
            }
        },
        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            target: {
                files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/css',
                        src: '**/*.css',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/css'
                    }]
            }
        },
        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        filerev: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.target %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.target %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.target %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                    '<%= yeoman.target %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        },
        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.target %>/index.html', '<%= yeoman.target %>/owa-mail.html', '<%= yeoman.target %>/owa-doc-setting.html', '<%= yeoman.target %>/owa-doc-upload-2016.html', '<%= yeoman.target %>/owa-doc-upload-2013.html', '<%= yeoman.target %>/owa-doc-upload-failed.html'],
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['concat', 'cssmin'],
                            copy: ['concat']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.target %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.target %>/css/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.target %>'],
                assetsDirs: [
                    '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                    '<%= yeoman.target %>/images',
                    '<%= yeoman.target %>/styles'
                ]
            }
        },
//     The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
//     By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
//     minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
//     to use the Usemin blocks.
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/styles',
                        src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/styles',
                        ext: '.min.css'
                    }]
            }
        },

        //refer: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options
        babel: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                sourceType: 'module', //no strict mode 3 option:  "script" | "module" | "unambiguous
                exclude: ['<%= yeoman.sources %>/scripts/lib']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                    src: [
                        '**/*.js'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        //append features if necessary : https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#features, or: target\node_modules\core-js\modules\
        polyfill: {
            options: {
                uglify: true,
                features: ['es5', 'es6.object.assign', 'es7.array.includes', 'es6.array.of', 'es6.array.find'],
                output: '<%= yeoman.target %>/scripts/lib/polyfill.js'
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: true
            }        
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    conservativeCollapse: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true
                },
                files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                        src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>'
                    }]
            }
        },
        // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
        // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
        ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/.tmp/concat/scripts/',
                        src: '*.js',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/.tmp/concat/scripts/'
                    }]
            }
        },
        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            target: {
                files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        dot: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                        src: [
                            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                            '.htaccess',
                            '*.html',
                            'views/{,*/}*.html',
                            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/office-web-addin',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                        src: ['**/*.html']
                    },
                    // {
                    //     expand: true,
                    //     cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>',
                    //     dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                    //     src: ['**/*.js']
                    // },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/components/themes',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/components/themes',
                        src: ['**']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/images',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/images',
                        src: ['**']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/resources',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/resources',
                        src: ['**/*.json', '**/*.jpg']
                    }]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                        expand: true,
                        dot: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                        src: [
                            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                            '.htaccess',
                            '*.html',
                            'views/{,*/}*.html',
                            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                            'scripts/**/*.js',
                            'styles/*.css',
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/images',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                        src: ['**']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/bower_components/xcomponent-widgets/pdfViewer/',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/xcomponent-widgets/pdfViewer/',
                        src: ['**/*.*']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/bower_components/xcomponent-widgets/components/object-display-storyline/TimelineJS/build/css',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles',
                        src: ['**']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/bower_components/xcomponent-widgets/TimelineJS/',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/xcomponent-widgets/TimelineJS/',
                        src: ['**/*.*']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/bower_components/pdf-tron-webviewer/',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/pdf-tron-webviewer/',
                        src: ['**/*.*']
                    },
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.target %>/resources',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/resources',
                        src: ['**/*.json', '**/*.jpg']
                    }
                    // We can add more resources to dist here, like the environments folder (refer to xgov)
                ]
            }
        },
        //create template.js file. Contain all template files.
        ngtemplates: {
            target: {
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/components/',
                src: ['**/*-template.html', '**/*-tpl.html', '**/template/*.html', '**/templates/*.html'],
                dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/xecm-webapp/template.js',
                options: {
                    module: "xecm-webapp",
                    url: function (url) {
                        var urlSp = url.split("/");
                        var p1 = urlSp.pop();
                        var p2 = urlSp.pop();
                        if (p2 == 'template' || p2 == 'templates')
                            return p2 + '/' + p1;
                        else
                            return p1;
                    },
                    htmlmin: {
                        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                        removeComments: true, // Only if you don't use comment directives!
                        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
                    }
                }
            },
            target3: {
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.sources %>/components/',
                src: ['**/office-auth-tpl.html'],
                dest: '<%= yeoman.target %>/xecm-webapp/template3.js',
                options: {
                    module: "owa-doc-setting",
                    url: function (url) {
                        var urlSp = url.split("/");
                        var p1 = urlSp.pop();
                        var p2 = urlSp.pop();
                        if (p2 == 'template' || p2 == 'templates')
                            return p2 + '/' + p1;
                        else
                            return p1;
                    },
                    htmlmin: {
                        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                        collapseWhitespace: true,
                        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                        removeComments: true, // Only if you don't use comment directives!
                        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });



// Task to build dev and dist folders
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean', // Clean all folders    
        'copy:target',
        'ngtemplates', //Generate templateCache
        'compass',
        'autoprefixer',
        'wiredep',
        'babel',
        'polyfill',
        'useminPrepare', //Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically  concat, minify and revision files.    
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin',
        'copy:dist',
        'appcache:all',
        'replace:manifest'
    ]);


};
```

in the index.html file I have this part for building of the css

```
    <!-- build:css styles/xxx-styles.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/components/document-basket-display-list/basket-document-display/basket-document-display.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/components/pdf-tron-web-viewer/pdf-tron-web-viewer.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->
```

So when I am on my dev server I can see that this css files are existing but on the prod server whole css code is put into one file. But I need also to have this  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/components/pdf-tron-web-viewer/pdf-tron-web-viewer.css" />` css file to exist on it's own also on my prod server and I am not able to do that.

I tried putting the linking of the css file outside of start and endbuild comments for the css part.

`build:css styles/xxx.css` and `endbuild`